# Are fewer fallacies better than more?

Tags: logic

In case you haven't already figured it out, I like to ask questions about how to measure soundness.

**Question a**

Suppose I haven two arguments, *X* and *Y*, each consisting of *p* premises. Suppose that argument *X* commits *f* > 0 fallacies, whereas argument *Y* commits *g* fallacies, where 0 < *g* < *f*. Could one say that argument *X* is worse than argument *Y* in terms of its soundness?

**Question b**

Suppose there are two entities, *X* and *Y*, each having made *a* arguments that average *p* premises each and have the same distribution of the number of premises per argument. Suppose that entity *X* commits *f* > 0 fallacies in total, whereas entity *Y* commits *g* fallacies in total, where 0 < *g* < *f* fallacies. Could one say that entity *X* is worse at making sound arguments than entity *Y*?

**Question c**

In Question a, what if the two arguments have a different ratio of fallacies to premises?

**Question d**

In Question b, what if the ratio of fallacies to arguments differs between the two entities?

**Question e**

In Question b, what if the distribution of the ratio of fallacies to premises differs between the two entities?

Comment: I think it's fairly obvious that fewer fallacies is better, no? Can you give one reason why more fallacies could possibly be better? As it stands, I don't see a real question here.

Comment: @Ben The alternative I'm interested in isn't that more fallacies is better. The alternative is that the number of fallacies doesn't matter. Only the presence or absence of any fallacy does. So, yes, there is indeed a "real" question here as opposed to, I don't know, a fake one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I like to ask questions about how to measure soundness.

Unfortunately, before we can go forward, we need to unpack some of the assumptions lying behind your question.

To begin with: measure the soundness of *what*?

Arguments of some kind, of course-- but are these *formal arguments*, or *natural language (i.e., rhetorical) arguments*?

If they are formal arguments, as soon as there is a logical fallacy, the argument fails.  Additional fallacies don't make much difference; it is like a mathematical proof with a erroneous step.

If, however, you are speaking of *informal arguments*, i.e., arguments in natural language, then the fallacies that you are speaking of are *rhetorical* in nature, and don't actually invalidate the argument at all.  They *fail to support* the argument, but don't undercut it from a *logical* perspective (although they may make it less persuasive psychologically.)

Note that this very question demonstrates the problem that we are dealing with.

Much depends upon how we interpret the terms "argument" and "fallacy"-- whether we are speaking of them in the context of formal logic, or in the context of rhetoric.  This ambiguity is a hallmark of natural language arguments, and necessarily so: words have meaning *in context*, and the context is never completely saturated.

In other words, attempts to apply the tools of mathematics (ratios of fallacies to premises) are bound to fail, as there is no way to unambiguously count premises or fallacies, since their recognition *depends upon an interpretive process dependent upon context*, and that context (in an non-formalized structure) *cannot be sufficient for epistemic closure.*

Comment: Excellent answer. I am dealing with rhetorical arguments that I ultimately wish to "score" in terms of their adherence to facts and logic. I agree with everything you said, but add that although I can't reach epistemic closure, I can estimate some underlying, latent structure to the argument and its validity by asking a number of people to reconstruct in a pseudo formal way and tag it appropriately with fallacies committed. Then I could somehow incorporate the uncertainty in the structure of the argument and the identified fallacies, likely using Bayesian inference.

Comment: You have two options, it seems to me. One is to just admit that you are being subjective, and assign scores to the arguments based on the strength that you perceive.  The other is to attempt to formalize the arguments, but this is a famously impossible task-- in fact, just trying to deduce whether or not a give chunk of text contains an argument, or to identify the premises within the text, seems to be far beyond current AI research.

Comment: We aren't using AI to start. We are using multiple raters.

Comment: Then you're back to option one: to recognize that you are working with subjective judgment, and that your scores will be subjective measures and not objective.

Comment: Of course they will be subjective measures but they can still be based on some underlying theory that is founded in facts an logic.

Comment: Of course.  But they still need to *interpret* the theory, and *apply* it to the particular case, which is going to rely on subjective judgments.  And if you are going to recognize the subjective element, you'll realize that there can be big differences between the persuasiveness of a rhetorical argument and its underlying logical argument.  I can make a perfectly cogent argument which might be rhetorically *strengthened* by the addition of certain rhetorical fallacies which *will not weaken the logical argument in any way.*

Comment: Yes, but at least it's better than upvotes, downvotes, and backlinks.

Comment: Perhaps; but that's more a function of the qualities of the people involved (grading or upvoting/downvoting, etc.)

Comment: I don't think we actually -know- which factor is more important: the system or the users. But I think it is pretty apparent that if you have a better system AND better users, it is better.